# Replace mysql column data to onther column with Match ID

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a WordPress database just updated to my site to a new theme and my Product specification is missing in new theme I try to find and found new theme using a different table column to show the specification so I have to replace product specifications in the new column.

Following the original data
Table Name: wp_postmeta

```
SELECT 
  wp_postmeta.post_id, 
  wp_postmeta.meta_value, 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key 
FROM 
  wp_postmeta 
WHERE 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_specifications' 
ORDER BY 
  wp_postmeta.post_id 
ASC
```

I want to replace above data in following table with matching ID
Table Name: wp_posts

```
SELECT 
  wp_posts.ID, 
  wp_posts.post_content 
FROM
  wp_posts 
ORDER BY 
  wp_posts.ID 
ASC
```

Comment: is wp_postmeta empty ?

Comment: no it is filled with "_specifications" that only rows i need to import else There are many wp_postmeta.meta_value are duplicate in table.

Comment: sorry i was meaning wp_posts

Comment: yes might be in some row had content in wp_posts.post_content that need to update or replace don't need to add just replace or update will be fine with wp_postmeta.meta_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the table `wp_posts` by joining it to your first query.

```
update wp_posts p inner join (
  select post_id, meta_value
  from wp_postmeta 
  where meta_key = '_specifications'
) m on m.post_id = p.id
set p.post_content = m.meta_value
```